# Rails 3 validate presence of many columns with custom messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Is there a way to specify many validations like this more concisely?

```
validates :col_a, :presence => {:message => 'col_a cannot be blank'}
validates :col_b, :presence => {:message => 'col_b cannot be blank'}
validates :col_c, :presence => {:message => 'col_c cannot be blank'}
```

I'd settle for a generic message if I had to.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can give multiple field names to a validator

```
validates :col_a, :col_b, :col_c, :presence => true
```

You can specify multiple validators in the same line.

```
validates :col_a, :col_b, :col_c, :presence => true, :numericality => true
```

The full error message will contain the field name. You don't need to add the field name prefix. If you want to use a custom message then:

```
validates :col_a, :col_b, :col_c, :presence => {:message => "empty value found"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```rb
validates :col_a, presence: true
validates :col_b, presence: true
validates :col_c, presence: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the validates_presence_of helper.

```
validates_presence_of :col_a
```

EDIT

You could clean it up a bit with validates_each. There is an example on the api page. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks.  I'm aware of the rails < 3 helper.  The question was (a) how to use the rails 3 style validator, (b) how to deal with multiple cols more concisely, hopefully with custom messages for each.

Comment: validates_each should clean it up for you